# mtree(8) & use of -O

Tags: freebsd

I am attempting to create a specification for files rooted in `/etc`, however, I am only interested in the path `/etc/rc.conf.d` & file `/etc/rc.conf.local`.  I am using FreeBSD-12 & can create specifications for either `/etc` or `/etc/rc.conf.d` successfully:

```
mtree -cx -K uname,gname,sha512 -p /etc/rc.conf.d/ -R uid,gid > /tmp/etc-conf-d.mtree
```

I would like to use `/etc` in the `-p` parameter, tho I would like to exclude a list of files.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding the man page, I thought `-O` would allow me to supply a list of files/paths to create the specification from.

From the mtree(8) man page:

> -O onlypaths       Only include files included in this list of pathnames.

However if I run:

```
mtree -cx -K uname,gname,sha512 -p /etc/ -O /etc/rc.conf.d/ -R uid,gid > /tmp/etc-conf-d.mtree
```

This produces a specification file with a header & no path specifications at all.  I am doing something wrong, or am I using the incorrect tool for the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I looked at the sources to figure this out, because the man page does not provide details that are really necessary to make this work. I found out the following.

The option `-O` needs to be a path to a text file containing a list of paths (note that "path" is terminologically different from "directory"). Each path is on one line in this file and needs to begin with the prefix `./` where the `.` is implicitly the current directory, which is the directory, you specified with `-p`.

It seems that file list given with the option `-O` is to be constructed with a tool like `find`. You cannot specify directories, but you need a list of full paths there (without duplicates, as far as I understood it).

Comment: You are correct, the path names must by preceded by a period.  Thanks for your help.